# Show the error message only once in SAP HCM Payroll?

Tags: error-handling, abap, sap-hr

I am doing some changes related to error messages in HCM Payroll.

I put the message into a table and call them and this works fine.

But now I'd like to supress this error message once it has been showed in past periods of the payroll.

**Example**: payroll of june 2022 triggers an error message. Then when I have payroll of july this message will be showed again and this has to be blocked. Once the message has been showed in a past payroll period it should not be showed anymore.

code:

```
  WHEN 'E27'.
      PERFORM append_line TABLES gt_error
        USING 'This amount'.
      PERFORM append_line TABLES gt_error
          USING 'is over the limit'.
```

The error message 27 has been showed in a past period it should not be showed again.

Comment: How would you know whether the message 1. occurred in the past period and 2. was shown to a user (or only this particular user)?

Comment: its is an error messages there is a report which 'runs' the payroll. if a particular situation occurs it will trigger the error message. the problem is that the error msg will be trigger every time in past payroll calculations.

Comment: So what do you *really* want? Do you want to suppress the error message if you are redoing a payroll calculation for a month which is not the current month? And what report specifically are you talking about? Is it a SAP standard report or is it a custom report?

Comment: i want to supress an error msg once it has been shown. payroll processes are started with the report RPCALCU0 (a sap standard). in some cases of the payroll, you have to do past caculations so the errors can be corrected. for example. last may something has been changed regarding payment rights/laws. so, i do the changes in the system now (nov. 2022) but this is going to work only from now on. that means that I have to roll the payroll since may and do the past caculations so erros can be corrected. the E message should appers only in may and not in furthers months.